# Embed ALL shapes of the fonts into PDF

Tags: fonts, luatex, embedding

I'm producing a book using **luatex**, and zillion other packages. Everything goes fine except that when I sent the PDF to a reviewer he told me that when he prints it some parts of the doc (*those using italics*) prints rubbish. So I need to EMBED all the font into the PDF.

Anyway thenks for advice on a more relevant MWE. Here it's. This is extracted from My code. The part between makeatletter & makeatother is taken from a custom package I use for all the books we produce.

The reviewer reported that anything produced by `\kote` macro is not shown.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setmainfont{Dejavu Sans}

\setlength\parskip{2mm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\L@KoteSkip}%
\newlength{\@NewTextWidth}%
\newlength{\L@DialogSkip}%

\pgfkeys{%
  /kote/.cd,
  color/.store in=\kote@color,
  sym/.store in=\kote@sym,
  wide/.store in=\kote@wide,
  shrink/.store in=\kote@shrink,
  color={Black},
  wide={false},
  shrink={false},
  sym={\Huge ``}
}

\newcommand{\shrinking}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{true}}%
  {%
    \setlength\parskip{1.5mm}%
    \setstretch{1}%
  }%
  {%
    \setlength\parskip{2mm}%
    \setstretch{1.1}%
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\kote}[2][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/kote/.cd, #1}% Inject optional args into the macro

  {% begin scope for the custom color
    \shrinking{\kote@shrink}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{\kote@wide}{true}}
      {\def\kote@full@sym{\kote@sym{\hspace*{10pt}}}}%
      {\def\kote@full@sym{\kote@sym{\hspace*{4pt}}}}%

    \settowidth{\L@KoteSkip}{\widthof{\kote@full@sym}} % store the width of the mark
    \setlength{\@NewTextWidth}{\textwidth}%
    \addtolength{\@NewTextWidth}{-2\L@KoteSkip}%
    \color{\kote@color}%
    \vspace*{1mm}\hspace*{-1\L@KoteSkip}{\kote@full@sym}%
    %%-- Push everythng to right
    \leftskip +1\L@KoteSkip%
    {\itshape{#2}}%

    %%-- Bring everythng back to its place
    \leftskip 0mm
  }

  %%-- Reset the default kote values
  \pgfkeys{%
    /kote/.cd,
    color={Black},
    wide={false},
    shrink={false},
    sym={\Huge ``}
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\kote{%
Whatever happens \\
I won the Supreme Battle \\
I loved \\
Again

Ladies and gentlemen! \\
This was meant to be a love story
}%

This text outside \verb|\kote| macro gets printed properly.

\end{document}
```

The snippet is produces the following PDF:

[image]

Thanks in advance

PS: The previous version of the question was based on a wrong assumption. Thanks @JasperHabicht & @ingmar to help me improving the question

Comment: No, you certainly don't have to use dvi to embed fonts (and with luatex you actually will run into problem if you produce dvi as dvips typically can't handle dvi created by luatex).

Comment: >> _No, you certainly don't have to use dvi to embed fonts..._

What's the alternative?
I didn't find any on SX or elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems that the relevant question here is: how to embed the relevant font to the PDF. It is very likely that this problem can be solved without switching to DVI (which would probably even confront you with more questions than it actually solves). It might rather be a problem with the font, maybe it cannot be embedded, maybe its encoding is not right or maybe something else is wrong with it. So, first you should identify which font it is that renders not properly and create a MWE that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks for adding information to your question. Now, where did you get the fonts that you use? I found various sources, but probably https://dejavu-fonts.github.io is the official one. Did you use the most current version of the fonts? You can check whether the fonts are embedded in your PDF using Acrobat Reader (go to File > Properties > Fonts). Also, why do you load the `dejavu` package *and* load the fonts via `fontspec`?

Comment: remove `\usepackage{dejavu}`. That is not meant for lualatex (you can use `\setmonofont{Dejavu Sans Mono}` for the typewriter font instead).  Add `\textit{some italic} {\color{Black} some black text}` to your document, compile and ask your reviewer which texts are printed.

Comment: Using the questions & hints in Jasper & Ulrike comments I'm revisiting the code. When I get a final version I send it to my reviewer & update the thread.

Gasper: I'm using the github version of DejaVu.
Ulrike: I like the flexibility that your suggestion offer. Whatever solution I end up with it should be easily adapted by many other books.

I'm relatively new to Latex and Fonts/Encodings have been one of my first nightmares. Today it on the top of my must-learn items. What you guy write here is part of the process.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that for flexibility, but to test if the font or the color settings are the problem.